# Using if conditions in shellscripting

Tags: bash, shell

```
read A
if [["$A" == 'Y' -o "$A" =='y']]
then echo "YES"
else echo "NO"
fi
```

I am very new to shell scripting.basically, i am trying to check if the input is `Y` or `y`.
I am getting the following error which I am not able to debug.

```
solution.sh: line 2: [[Y: command not found
```

Thanks.

Comment: Give space after `[[`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing space after `[[`

The if should be like

```
if [[ "$A" == 'Y' || "$A" == 'y' ]]
```

---

The `[[ ]]` is an  [extended test command](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS), like any command it should be separated from others by spaces

Answer (score 1):

Add proper space inside the square brackets and after the `==`:

```
read A
if [ "$A" == 'Y' -o "$A" == 'y' ]; then 
    echo "YES";
else 
    echo "NO";
fi
```

Note that to use `-o` you ought to use `test` command, which uses *single brackets*.

If you use **[[ ]]**, with *double brackets*, you must use `||` instead of `-o`:

```
read A
if [[ "$A" == 'Y' || "$A" == 'y' ]]; then 
    echo "YES";
else 
    echo "NO";
fi
```

Comment: Do i have to use the ; symbol here? Even if i use it or not use it i am still getting errors.  solution.sh: line 2: syntax error in conditional expression
solution.sh: line 2: syntax error near `-o'
solution.sh: line 2: `if [[ "$A" == 'Y' -o "$A" =='y' ]];then '

Comment: @VaibhavSavala fixed